# Stylizing software names in LaTeX?

Tags: typography

In scientific text (papers; proposals) what is the convention for formatting the following?

- operating systems: Android; Linux; Microsoft Windows
- software (suite), e.g.: LibreOffice; Microsoft Office

  - components: Writer (LibreOffice); Word (MS Office)
- platforms, e.g.: Apache Solr; Cytoscape; Java platform
- frameworks, e.g.:  PostgreSQL; MySQL
- libraries, e.g.: jQuery (JS); Matplotlib (Python); NetworkX (Python); NumPy (Python)
- markup languages, e.g.: HTML
- programming languages, e.g.: C; Java; JavaScript; PHP; PSQL; Python; R
- runtime environment: node

  - package manager: npm
- stylesheets, e.g.: CSS
- data structures, e.g.: JSON; XML

I'm not sure where to draw the line: i.e. style all programmatic mentions, or exclude some common ones (HTML?).

Also, is the preferred use for those stylings teletype: `\texttt{}` or (per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620961/171556) SmallCaps: `\textsc{}`?

I found this which offers some guidance:

- O'Reilly Typography and Font Conventions: https://oreillymedia.github.io/production-resources/styleguide/#typography_and_font_conventions

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This is primarily opinion based, and therefore probably off topic.  If you know how you want the output to appear, then we would be glad to help you figure out the appropriate input.

Comment: Victoria is really up to you and the overall style of your write-up. All capitals are intrusive generally when mixed with lower case text, so IMHO words like HTML, XML etc you can use small caps.  Microsoft Word, though is not intrusive at all, treat it as you would write Victoria Stuart in a paragraph. Best write a paragraph and test various styles until you happy with it.  @Teepeemm don't be so quick to declare opinion based  topics, some are very valid and in the early days of this site many questions like this, had some superb answers.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It might not be opinion-based because there are certainly norms, style guides etc., but it does seem off-topic for this site. Perhaps it belongs on a different site? I suspect the answer depends on many factors, including discipline and journal (or publisher or conference or whatever). But the answer doesn't really have anything to do with TeX - no more than it has to do with LibreOffice or Calligra.

Comment: @cfr  What I am saying is that the universe is not going to collapse in a black hole, if a question like this can be let through, where experience based answers might be useful. We have a tag for `typography` in any case. I would love to know what you or egreg or barbara or Knuth would have answered here. I do not know what happened to the meta, otherwise I would open a topic for this.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Honestly, I think it is more interesting than many questions on the site and more generally useful. But that's true for lots of possible questions.

Comment: @VictoriaStuart What you might want to do is create a macro to mark the things up semantically. Then you can easily change it later if necessary. E.g. `\NewDocumentCommand \progacro {m} {\textsc{\texttt{#1}}}` and `\NewDocumentCommand \proglib {m} {\texttt{#1}}` or whatever. That gets you a lot more flexibility. And this aspect of it certainly *is* on-topic, even if exactly what the commands should ideally do isn't.

Comment: When you publish most publishers will have a styleguide. Styles vary from publisher to publisher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than marking up items using `\texttt{}` or `\textsc{}`, I'd recommend using semantic markup so you can easily modify the formatting if you find you want or need something different.

Basically, this involves creating a bunch of simple wrappers in your preamble, such as

```
\NewDocumentCommand \os {m} {\textsf{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \suite {m} {\texttt{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \suitecomp {m} {\texttt{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \langacro {m} {\textsc{\texttt{#1}}}
```

and so on. You then use these wrappers, rather than explicit markup, in your document,

```
\os{Linux} distributions package \suite{LibreOffice}, which includes \suitecomp{Writer} and \suitecomp{Calc}.
```

The documentation for the `doc` package may be a useful, as may the abundance of [packages for typesetting package documentation on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/topic/doc-supp).

Comment: It could also make sense to use a package like acro or glossaries.

Comment: Another advantage of semantic mark-up is that you you can make the macro add  the item to an index or link automatically to ctan for example if it is for LaTeX packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is probably right. I've only ever used glossaries for glossaries, but acronyms just get defined in parentheses in my field and are just author-specific shorthands. Logic uses some, but a list of acronyms doesn't really help.